# How to upgrade to a newer version of elementary os?

Tags: system, updates

As far as i know, there are no tools or ways to upgrade to a new relase, am i right? If not, does the typyng in a terminal:

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

leads to a version upgrade, once a new one is relased? Or mperaphs if users do regularly install updates the will have it?

Answer (score 2):

`apt dist-upgrade` does not upgrade your system to a different release, rather it upgrades existing packages, and installs any new dependencies which may be required by these packages. See my answer [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/7496/5722) if you want a more detailed explanation.

`do-release-upgrade` is used to upgrade to a new OS release on Ubuntu, however **this does not work on elementary**. Instead, elementary currently requires a clean install each time you move between major OS versions (e.g. Freya to Loki).

Answer (score 1):

All OS internal updates will now be pushed by the new AppCenter introduced in Loki. However, to upgrade from one version of elementary OS to another you would have to do a clean install of the newer version. As in future, OTA updates might be possible, so no you can't use `sudo apt dist-upgrade` to update to a newer OS version.

Comment: Thanks! Please may be subjrct a request so that such function may be implemented and handkrd in/by AppCenter? Over and out :)