# Unable to update (from AppCenter or Terminal)

Tags: updates, pantheon-terminal, appcenter, sudo

I hadn't updated elementaryOS for a while.

My OSupdate has 29 components with update in the Appcenter.

If I am in the Appcenter and click on Update, the OS asks my password and then the update cancels itself, and I don't know why.

I thought, if I cannot update with the Appcenter, then I can update with Terminal. I tried following commands (from [Update with terminal instead of AppCenter](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7490/update-with-terminal-instead-of-appcenter)) :

**sudo apt update** : I then have in the Appcenter the following message : "Failed to fetch updates - This may have been caused by external, manually added software repositeries or a corrupted sources file." (see the image below)

**sudo apt full-upgrade** : E: dkpg was interrupted, you must manually run "sudo dkpg --configure -a" to resolve the problem

**sudo apt-get update** : in the Terminal I read Reading package list...done
In the Appcenter I have the same error message as with sudo apt update

**sudo apt-get dist-upgrade** : same error message as with sudo apt full-upgrade

[image: image description : my error with sudo apt update and sudo apt-get update]

I just hope someone knows how to deal with this. Perhaps with another command text or if I could understand the error messages and what to do with them.

Anyway thanks to anyone trying to help.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo dkpg --configure -a` ?

Comment: It answers "sudo: dkpg: command not found". I thought I coudn't use the sudo dkpg command because it is the first time I use it.

Comment: Perhaps there are other commands to ask the OS to upgrade. I also have Firefox updates to make.

Comment: Go to folder `/usr/bin` and see if `dpkg` (and other files, which names begin with dpkg) is there.

Comment: There is a dpkg file with 23 other dpkg files (from dpkg-architecture to dpkg-vendor). Tell me all other info you need.

Comment: Looks like `dpkg` is installed, but your system can't find it. Maybe your 'path' variable has been modified? Please enter `echo $PATH` command and supply the output.

Comment: Result of the echo $PATH in the Terminal :

Comment: /home/shinobi/bin:/home/shinobi/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

Comment: Hmm... `dpkg` is present in your system and `/usr/bin` (directory where dpkg is located) is included in your path variable. I'm sorry, I must admit, at this point I don't understand how to fix this issue, except for complete system reinstall. Maybe that'll be a quicker solution than waiting.

Comment: I've launched again "sudo dkpg --configure -a" and this time it worked (and it took more than half an hour). After that "sudo apt upgrade" worked (again, more than half an hour). I don't know why it worked this time and not before. But I'm glad that now I have no update to do anymore. Thanks for your help.